# How to hide Kopete on KDE taskbar?

Tags: debian, kde, plasma, kopete

I am using Debian Stretch with KDE Plasma. Today I discovered fine and flexible instant messaging application, Kopete.I could configure there everything I want and use two networks, gtalk and gg. But how can I hide Kopete from KDE Taskbar? I would like it to behave like Skype or Pidgin, just leave contact list on screen and free taskbar.

[image]